# How do I dim the background for an android spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to dim the background around a spinner dropdown, but I cannot find any way to accomplish this.

Research has uncovered the possibility of placing a fullsize framelayout between the activity and the spinner dropdown, and setting a background colour and alpha value on this.

However, I cannot find anyway to determine when the actual dropdown is getting displayed so that I can insert this frame.

Am I looking at this problem the wrong way? Surely there must be a way to dim the background behind a spinner dropdown.

Comment: I do not think, putting a framelayout is a good way to solve this issue. Your question is a possible duplicate to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188398/how-to-change-the-spinner-background-design-and-color-for-android

Comment: It's quite likely that it might not be the best way to solve this issue, but it's the closest thing I've found to an answer so far. 
I'm not trying to change the background of the dropdown itself. I need to "dim" the background around the actual dropdown, basically, gray out the underlying activity while the spinner dropdown is open.

Comment: For reference, this is the only thing resembling an answer I've been able to find
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405177/android-spinner-dim-background

Comment: mhm interesting... You might wanna check this clue of customization then... http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't help solve my problem either. All it does is allow for creating custom listview items in the dropdown.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem,  JymmyZ, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something very similar to this answer in a related question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636385

Along with a RelativeLayout in the activity to act as a dimming mask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use the Spinner.OnClickListener. When this is called, you can dim the screen with your framelayout

Comment: Spinners do not allow onClick listeners. That just crashes the app

Comment: Which OnClickListener did you use? Try to use View.OnClickListener for this and if that doesn't work try DialogInterface.OnClickListener

Comment: Can you post some code? That way we can also figure out the best solution